# Is there a way to change the value of a picklist on a vf page when it is copied from another picklist?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning, javascript, visualforce-component

So I have a form that has 2 Address divisions. When the checkbox is checked the field values from one div copy to the other div. There is a country picklist in both the divs. But the value of that picklist doesn't reflect on the other picklist. I've used javascript to copy field values.

[image]

When I change the value of the first picklist,the value in the other picklist doesn't change.

Comment: You may do this with `apex:actionFunctino`. Have a look on that to get an understanding about how to call Apex from actionFunction and rerender a given section/output panel.

Comment: The problem is that the value that is displayed on the country field doesn't change. The value of the picklist although changes but it doesn't show it on the field. It displays the old value.

Comment: Can you post the relevant code snippet for this?

Answer (score 2):

Put an **actionSupport** apex tag in you first picklist and rerender the second one...

**Example::**

```
<apex:page controller="YourCustomCntrller">
<apex:form >
    <apex:pageBlock>
        <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
            <apex:pageblockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel value="Billing Country"/>
            </apex:pageblockSectionItem>        
            <apex:pageblockSectionItem>                
                <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!billingCountry}">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!billingCountries}"/>
                    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" reRender="shippingOption"/>
                </apex:selectList>                
            </apex:pageblockSectionItem>
            <apex:pageblockSectionItem>
                <apex:outputLabel value="Shipping Country"/>
            </apex:pageblockSectionItem>            
            <apex:pageblockSectionItem>
                <apex:selectList size="1" value="{!shippingCountry}" id="shippingOption">
                    <apex:selectOptions value="{!shippingCountries}"/>
                </apex:selectList>
            </apex:pageblockSectionItem>            
        </apex:pageBlockSection>        
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
```

Rest of you logic of copying one to another will remain same.

Above is just an hypothetical example.

Put the same values in both shippingCountries and billingCountries which will used to render the List options.